# Best way to markup search results?

Tags: html, list, search

Currently I'm using:
    `<dl>
    <dt>Title/Link</dt>
    <dd>Description</dd>
    </dl>`

But I would like my results to be numbered. Should I just do this by including an incremented variable in the PHP loop which generates the results, or could I use `<ol> <li>Title<br />Description</li></ol>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `list-style-type:decimal;` [css property](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/list-style-type) to get numbers.

`<ul>` and `<dl>` makes good sense. Personally I use unordered lists for search results, unless the enumeration adds schemantic context.

Comment: Is it valid to have a dl as each li?
e.g. `<ol>
<li><dl><dt>Item Name</dt><dd>Item description</dd></dl></li>
</ol>`

Comment: @user1765369 Making a list with one list point effectively seems odd to me. However, if it makes sense in your context, go ahead.

Comment: No that was just an example, it would have several list items (one for each search result).